# how to prevent ALAssetsLibrary to get video thumbnail images with liabrary images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, alassetslibrary, alasset

I'm using the following code to access all ALAssetsLibrary images but the ALAssetsLibrary is giving me the saved video thumbnail images with the saved images from ALAssetsLibrary. how can i prevent this using the code so that i can get only saved images?

```
//Method to get all images from devices library
 - (NSMutableArray*)getAllImagesFromLibrary
 {
     //get all images from image library
     void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
     if(result != NULL) {
         //Insert objects into array
         [self.arrOfAllImages addObject:result];
        }
     };

     void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
     if(group != nil) {
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
     };

     //NSMutableArray allacation
     NSMutableArray *arrOfAllImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
     static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
     dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
         library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
     });

     [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
     usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure");
     }];

     return arrOfAllImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your result, If it will image the add in array otherwise not

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != NULL) {
        if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
        {
            //Insert objects into array
            [self.arrOfAllImages addObject:result];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a [filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) before you enumerate:

```
[group setAssetsFilter: [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mention many types of Asset through **ALAssetsGroupType**

They are

```
   ALAssetsGroupLibrary        
   ALAssetsGroupAlbum          
   ALAssetsGroupEvent          
   ALAssetsGroupFaces          
   ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos    
   ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream    
   ALAssetsGroupAll
```

1

> **ALAssetsGroupLibrary**
>
> The Library group that includes all assets that are synced from
>   iTunes.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.

2

> **ALAssetsGroupAlbum**
>
> All the albums created on the device or synced from iTunes, not
>   including Photo Stream or Shared Streams
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.

3

> **ALAssetsGroupEvent**
>
> All events, including those created during Camera Connection Kit
>   import.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.

4

> **ALAssetsGroupFaces**
>
> All the faces albums synced from iTunes.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.

5

> **ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos**
>
> All the photos in the Camera Roll.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.

6

```
**ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream**

The PhotoStream album.

In iOS 6.0 and later, this also includes Shared Streams.

Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.
```

7

> **ALAssetsGroupAll**
>
> The same as ORing together all the group types except for
>   ALAssetsGroupLibrary.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in `ALAssetsLibrary.h`.

You can see more details [developer.apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-SW16)

**Example**:

```
 [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
     usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure");
     }];
```